"Proving Two Boys Share Both First and Last Names in a Class of 14"
Problem
There are $14$ boys in a class. Each boy is asked how many other boys in the class have his first name, and how many have his last name. It turns out that each number from $0$ to $6$ occurs among the answers. Prove that there are two boys in the class with the same first name and the same last name.

My Work
I’ve been thinking about a problem involving $14$ boys in a class, where each boy is asked how many other boys share his first name and how many share his last name. The given information is that each number from $0$ to $6$ appears among the answers.
Here’s what I’ve figured out so far:
Let’s denote the number of boys with the same first name as boy $i$ by $f_i$ and the number of boys with the same last name as boy $i$ by $l_i$. It seems that we’re working with the values of $f_i$ and $l_i$ such that every number from 0 to 6 is represented among the responses.
I was thinking about the Pigeonhole Principle here. Since there are only $7$ possible answers ($0$ through $6$) and $14$ boys, there must be some overlap in the combinations of first and last names. However, I’m struggling to formalize this overlap to show that there must be two boys who share both a first name and a last name.
One thought I had was to consider the total number of boys with each possible first name or last name, but I’m unsure how to proceed from there. Am I on the right track by using the Pigeonhole Principle, or is there a better approach to show that two boys must have the same first and last names?
Any help or insights would be appreciated!


First, we need to correctly understand the word 'share'. The answer $0$ is valid. So, when a boy says that $n$ boys share his firstname, it means that $n$ other boys have his firstname.  When a boy says that $6$ boys share his firstname or lastname, we have a total of $7$ boys with this firstname or lastname. And we can see that $1+2+3+4+5+6+7=28=14 \times 2$ ; it is not enough to conclude, but it is certainly a good starting point.

Notice that if no two boys have the same first and last name, then every boy must have said the number 0 for one (or both) of his two responses. Combine this with the above comment.

If one of the boys says there are $n$ other boys with the same first or last name then there are $n+1$ boys with that same first or last name, respectively. Since the answers range from $0$ to $6$, the number of boys who share either a first or a last name are grouped into sets of size $1,2,\dots, 7$, respectively.
Notice that the the two relations, "has the same first name" and "has the same last name" are equivalence relations. Therefore, each of these relations gives rise to a partion of the $14$ boys. Also, the sum of the numbers from $1$ to $7$ is $28$ and, since each of the answers must be used, each equivalence class will use each of the numbers once.
One of the partitions, say the boys with the same first name has $7$ elements. Then, the possible partitions of the boys with the same first name are $$(7,6,1), (7,5,2), (7,4,3), (7,1,2,4)$$ which means that the possible partitions for boys with the same last name are $$(2,3,4,5), (1,3,4,6), (1,2,5,6), (3,5,6)$$
Since the number of different last names is at most $4$ and there are seven boys with the same first name, at least two of them must have the same last name as well.

@GregMartin Are you serious? You changed the wording to be more inclusive! What value does that add? Are classrooms no longer permitted to consist of all boys?

Mathematics communities are pervasively biased towards males. Every bit of inclusion helps combat that bias.

@GregMartin Edits should be to make a post clearer, not to reflect your political biases. Also, in this case, a uniform gender makes more sense because we are comparing first names. Although there are many gender-neutral names, the question makes more sense with one gender.

@JohnDouma I've reverted Greg Martin's edits.

Note that 7 boys share either a first name or a last name (the one asked and 6 others, at least once). Without loss of generality, assume it's their first names.
Now 7 boys share a first name, so among the last names, there must be at least 7 different options for their to be no repeat full names. However, by the pigeonhole principle, we actually run out of first and last name responses. Each question gives the answers from 1 to 7, so all 28 first and last name slots for 14 children are filled. Therefore, at least one of the kids with the same 7 first names must also share a last name, as there were only 6 other options based on the repeat answers.

Lovely simplification that avoids further casework of John's solution.

If we assume for the sake of a contradiction that there are no two students with the same first and last name, that means that each student gives at least one $0$ as their two answers. In other words, we have at most $14$ non-zero numbers given.
If one student answers that $n$ other students share their first/last name, then all those $n$ other students in turn answer $n$. Thus, since there is one $6$ amongst the at most $14$ non-zero numbers, there are at least $6$ sixes there. Hence, we have at most $8$ numbers between $1$ and $5$. Same reasoning applies to $5$, so we have at most $3$ students naming numbers between $1$ and $4$, but then none of them can actually name $4$, contradiction.
